# How to delete SDcard file in Android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I tried to delete the image file from the gallery, but it won't. Image files are output normally, and sharing functions are done. It can't write and delete in my App. Files are deleted from the default app.
I tried to delete it use File class and ContentResolver. but file has not been deleted.
Android targetSdkVersion is 26 and compileSdkVersion is 28.

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I get SDcard path from getSDcardPath()

```
public String getSDcardPath(Context context) {
   File[] storage = ContextCompat.getExternalFileDirs(context, null);

   if(storage.length > 1 && storage[0] != null && storage[1] != null)
     return storage[1].toString();
   else
     return "";
}
```

File Class code Used

```
public void useFileClass() {
   File mFile = new File("file Parent + file NAME");

   if (mFile.exists()) {
   mFile.delete();
   }
}
```

ContentResolver code Used

```
public void useContentResolver(Context context, File mFile) {

   ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
   Uri mUri = getUri(context, mFile);

   contentResolver.delete(mUri, null, null);
}

public Uri getUri(Context context, File mFile) {
   Uri mUri;

   mUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "MyApplication", mFile);
   return mUri;
}
```

share code

```
public void shareImage() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getUri(this, mFile));

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image too..."));
    }
```

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() has nothing to do with a removable micro SD card. Please rename your functions and describe your problem less confusing.

Comment: `new File("file Parent + file NAME");` ??? Please provide real code.

Comment: "file Parent+ file NAME" is not real code. The file path is entered at "file Parent+ file NAME"

Comment: Please post real code.

Comment: File mFile = new File("/storage/421E-25A8/DCIM/100HSCAM/SING0084.JPG");

Comment: Post all real code in your post. Not in comments. Make a decent post to begin with.

Comment: And.. better.. you should show in your code where and how you use the obtsined sd card path. As niw we dont know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need request Permission before access into storage. Try this:

```
private static final int MY_WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 200;    

private void checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        } else {
            // Todo (Add, Delete, Edit, ...)
        }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, 
            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    if(requestCode == MY_WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Todo (Add, Delete, Edit, ...)
        } else {
            // Permission Deny
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I try it. But, "permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" was checked to contain Manifest. Unable to delete the file.. Thank you for sharing me how to check permission.